# Adding a new custom field/column to the content admin

Tags: php, drupal-7, admin

I've been able to add an element to the bottom of the table. Although I am unsure how you ADD a coloumn into the body of the table?

```
function seven_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        drupal_set_message("Form ID is : " . $form_id);

        //get node_admin_content
        //$nodeAdmin = drupal_get_form("node_admin_content");


          // Add a checkbox to registration form about agreeing to terms of use.
  $form['node_admin_content']['poland'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox', 
    '#title' => t("I agree with the website's terms and conditions."), 
    '#required' => TRUE,
  );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table is built by [`node_admin_nodes()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.admin.inc/function/node_admin_nodes/7) and comes in a nice render array so you can override it:

```
// Get the header array and add your new column header
$header = $form['admin']['nodes']['#header'];
$header['new_column'] = array('data' => 'New Col Header');
$form['admin']['nodes']['#header'] = $header;

// Get the table rows and add your new column to each.
// The function used to output the table depends on the user permissions
// so you need to check what type of object is being rendered.
if (isset($form['admin']['nodes']['#options'])) {
  $row_key = '#options';
}
else {
  $row_key = '#rows';
}

$rows = $form['admin']['nodes'][$row_key];

foreach ($rows as $nid => $row) {
  $form['admin']['nodes'][$row_key][$nid]['new_column'] = array('data' => 'Text');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help man. So how do we populate the coloumn with a) live data - and b) how are we able to make it orderable asc, desc?

Comment: That's a lot trickier I'm afraid, the query is hard coded in `node_admin_nodes()` and the order by header is added to that query before the it's executed. The only way I can think would be to essentially re-write your own version of` node_admin_nodes()`, adding the new headers/joins to the query and replacing the output of `$form['admin']['nodes']` altogether. If any of that doesn't make sense just ask another question someone'll be able to help. Also check out http://drupal.stackexchange.com/, it's a good resource for Drupal devs :)

Comment: Thanks - I needed to remove a column from the table, and this code helped me a lot!